# Is Ubuntu Server able to boot partitioned as MBR?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, mbr, usb-installation

I have a modified Dell Inspiron 530 (A Legacy Model) and I cant seem to install the server on it. Anyone able to help?

If there is a way to get it to work, give me (relatively) dumbed down answers, as my computer knowledge is not all to strong yet I am still studying.

Problem:
When I boot up the computer, it will not boot from the USB, even though i have gone into the Bios and set it to do so. When this is done, all I get back is an error looking like this:

- **No boot device available, Press ENTER key to retry**
- **SATA-0: Installed**
- **SATA-1: None**
- **SATA-4: Installed**
- **SATA-5: None**

Comment: There are one of two problems: (1) You didn't create the LiveUSB correctly, or (2) your system doesn't support USB boot.  If the system is truly 'legacy' enough, it'll be the second of these.  Have you tried to boot to the USB stick you're using from another system to verify the USB is properly created and works?  (Even if you don't install the system, testing to see if you can boot to the stick on another system wouldn't hurt)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar problems to that which you have described. My first step was to check the USB and see if I could boot from it using a different machine.

In my case, the USB was fine, and I think the machine that was giving me trouble was a Dell as well, but I can't say for sure. I played with all of the BIOS settings, and yeah, mine too were all set up so that I should have been able to boot from USB. In the end, I pulled the CD/DVD iso file and burned a disc, and that worked fine when a USB wouldn't.